# VS 2015 is not debugging properly

Tags: winforms

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015. I am working on winforms. I dont know why but my changes on a particular winform is not being shown.

I previously had label3 on my form but I removed that from everywhere. Even from the designer code. However, it is still showing label3.

I added a textbox but my textbox is not being displayed while debugging.

No errors anywhere. What is wrong with this thing? Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the solution in the Solution Explorer and select "Clean", then when that's finished, right click again and select "Rebuild".

Comment: wow that worked. You saved me pal. Tons of thanks. Sorry I could not mark your answer due to lack of enough reputation.

Comment: No worries. I know the feeling. The way the reputation works on here is stupid. The amount of questions answered in a comment is irritating too. Glad I could help. Hopefully someone else will see I answered and up vote my answer.